# Extending images from left and right sides of text to edges of screen while maintaining page layout?

Tags: css, image, layout, flexbox, background-image

I'm trying to design a page header style where two images *start* from either side of header text, and extend outward to the full width of the screen. Meanwhile, the position of the header text needs to stay left-aligned with the position of the other page content that flows below it, which has a width of 100% but a max-width of 1280px. I don't want the images to be cut off by the text.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Image showing tight width screen vs. large width screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDJoW.png)

I want the text to not cut off the circles seen on its left and right sides.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried positioning the two images using ::before and ::after, however, I haven't found a way to set the start of those pseudo-elements to the start and end of the text span.
- I could just set a background image on a full-width container containing the header text, but then I'd have to apply a white background to the header text span, which leads to cutting off of the image as it goes behind the text -- not ideal.
- Display:flex gets me closest to the behaviour I want (with left and right divs hugging either side of the div containing the text span and filling the rest of the screen space), however, no straightforward way to make sure the left edge of the text is aligned to the left edge of the rest of the body content. The flex solution works if I wanted centered text, but I need left-aligned text.

CSS grid is something I've considered but it seems like I wouldn't get the hugging behaviour I want while still aligning well with page content.

Thanks!

--EDIT: I tried to include some code of the best solution I have gotten so far which was with display:flex. I had to simplify it from my source code and couldn't get this to run, unfortunately, apologies as I'm quite new to posting on S.O.. --

```
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  }

.page-header {
  display:flex;
  background-color:#fff;
  }

  
  .left {
  flex:auto;
  background-image: url("[image]");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-position: right bottom 20px;
  }
 
 .text {
 flex:initial;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 1280px;
 }
 
 .right {
  flex:auto;
  background-image: url("[image]");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-position: left bottom 20px;
  }


.body-content-wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 2.5%;
  background-color: #333;
  }
```

and

```
<body>
  <div class=“page-header”>
    <div class=“left”>The left image</div>
    <div class=“text”><h1>The page header text</h1></div>
    <div class=“right”>The right image</div>
  </div>
  <div class=“body-content-wrapper”>
    [rest of page content]
  </div>
</body>
```

*EDIT*
Here's an image of what I'm trying to avoid with the header image: it being "cut off" on either side of the text (the left-side dots in the header should start at the left side of the text and extend to the edge of the screen, while the right-side dots should start at the immediate right side of the text and extend rightward to the edge of the screen).

[image: Showing not wanting to cut off text]

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of what you've tried so far? That will give us more to go off of. Also, to be clear: it looks like the images may change in width, but their *proportions* will always be the same? e.g. each of the bottom images will always take up 1/3 of the width, although the width may change.

Comment: Hi! I've attempted to add a simplified version of the closest I got (with centered text instead of left-aligned). I didn't get to a point of having a version where I could align the left edges of both the header text and the body content.

Comment: Oh! To answer your other question: The types of content below the header will change page by page, and all nested items currently have widths that follow a responsive grid of thirds (based on floats, currently, I haven't implemented CSS grid). The page header is the only thing that should "break out" of the grid, although the left side of the header text should  always align to the left edge of parent container of all remaining page content. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `:before` and `:hover`. As long as you know your `max-width` then you should be fine with a combination of `max-width`, setting your left and right margins to `auto`, and using flexbox for the image columns.

Note that I'm using `max-width: 500px` in the example below so it fits within the StackOverflow page a bit nicer.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Iypn3mA.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 50%;
}

.header .container {
  display: flex;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.columns > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.columns > :not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>I am some variable text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/2400x800?text=hero" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="container columns">
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: feels better now with that litlle sentence at front ;)

Comment: Thanks (and nice reuse of my terrible page title ;))! So, just so I'm clear, what method would I now use to insert the images to the left and right of the text span in the header? I added a code example of what I was trying to do earlier in my post, if that helps--was attempting to achieve it with bkg images.

Comment: @KRH Is the image the little dots/bubbles? I thought that was just showing where background color would go. Instead of putting images on the left and right, I'd suggest using `background-image`. I'll update my code.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin -- Thanks! Yes, those images are the core of my problem -- I want them to sit to the left and the right of the header text without the text overlapping them/cuttng them off, extending to full width of the screen while the text stays left aligned to the page content container and maxed at 1280 (I think everyone was solving for the three boxes near the bottom of the page, but I was just using those to illustrate what other page content might exist in the page content container :)).

Comment: @RobertAKARobin I added an image of the effect I'm trying to avoid, if that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using calc()

You won't see the dots image in this example but can see how the left and right header divs allow me to position the background image relative to the start and end of the page title text, without being cut off by the page title div.

```css
.header-parent {
    background-color:#fff;
    display:flex;
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.body-parent {
    position: relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}

article {
    padding: 10px;
}

.left-dots {
    width: calc((100% - 300px) / 2);
  background-color:#78AA56;
  background-image: url("img.png");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: right bottom 20px;
}

.title {
    flex:initial;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin:0 10px;
}

.right-dots {
    background-color:#CC4483;
  background-image: url("img.png");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom 20px;
    flex:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-parent">
    <div class="left-dots"></div>
    <div class="title"><h1>Page title</h1></div>
    <div class="right-dots"></div>
</div>
<div class="body-parent">
  <article>text text text text
    Body text
  Where its left margin lines up with the page title margin
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac dictum nisi. In vulputate in purus non laoreet. Nullam non ligula congue, porta lorem fermentum, feugiat urna. Quisque mollis nisl et risus malesuada vulputate. Nullam id efficitur odio, quis interdum augue. Praesent volutpat bibendum tellus, non pellentesque arcu. .</article>
</div>
```